# lync - answered calls are detected as missed

Tags: lync, lync-2013, skype-for-business

lync (skype for business) is detecting calls I answered as missed. I have no clue as to how even to begin to troubleshoot. contacting the administrator is not an option since I am the administrator. I just don't know enough about lync.